# Searchkick reindexing but search doesnt work unless full word is given

Tags: searchkick

I have an Artist model with

```
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    description: description
  }
end
```

I create two artists

```
Artist.create(name: "Da Vinci", description: "Tortuga")
Artist.create(name: "Donatello", description: "Tortoise")
```

Then reindex them

```
Artist.reindex
```

Perform a general search

```
Artist.search("*").results
```

It returns

```
=> [#<Artist id: 295, name: "Donatello", description: "Tortuga", avatar: nil, cover: nil, created_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:21", updated_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:21">, #<Artist id: 296, name: "Da Vinci", description: "Tortuga", avatar: nil, cover: nil, created_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:52", updated_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:52">]
```

So i conclude the artists where indexed correctly
I make a search

```
Artist.search("D").results
```

But it only returns

```
=> [#<Artist id: 296, name: "Da Vinci", description: "Tortuga", avatar: nil, cover: nil, created_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:52", updated_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:52">]
```

The only way I can get to the Donatello without searching "*" is literally

```
Artist.search("Donatello").results
```

That returns

```
=> [#<Artist id: 295, name: "Donatello", description: "Tortuga", avatar: nil, cover: nil, created_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:21", updated_at: "2018-10-25 13:43:21">]
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

-- UDAPTE --

I want to literally do this query

```
search("*", page: page, per_page: per_page, where: { _or: [ { name: /.*#{query}.*/ }, { description: /.*#{query}.*/ } ] })
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at:

#### [Partial Matches](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#partial-matches)

By default, results must match all words in the query.

`ruby
Product.search "fresh honey" # fresh AND honey`

To change this, use:

`ruby
Product.search "fresh honey", operator: "or" # fresh OR honey`

By default, results must match the entire word - `back` will not match `backpack`. You can change this behavior with:

`ruby
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick word_start: [:name]
end`

And to search (after you reindex):

`ruby
Product.search "back", fields: [:name], match: :word_start`

Available options are:

Option | Matches | Example
--- | --- | ---
`:word` | entire word | `apple` matches `apple`
`:word_start` | start of word | `app` matches `apple`
`:word_middle` | any part of word | `ppl` matches `apple`
`:word_end` | end of word | `ple` matches `apple`
`:text_start` | start of text | `gre` matches `green apple`, `app` does not match
`:text_middle` | any part of text | `een app` matches `green apple`
`:text_end` | end of text | `ple` matches `green apple`, `een` does not match

The default is `:word`. The most matches will happen with `:word_middle`.

Answer (score 2):

There was an answer that was correct but incomplete.
The solution was to use Partial Matches, in my case match: :text_middle

The thing that was missing was, I had to change my model to use text_middle

```
searchkick callbacks: :async, text_middle: [:name, :description]
```

and the search query to

```
Artist.search("D", match: :text_middle).results
```